# Pathfinding algorithm using every node to reach endpoint

Tags: java, path-finding

This is my first question on the forum so forgive any mistakes made. I have been playing a game called "fill" on my phone and it inspired me to create a small java program that would solve any given problem in game that I could not solve myself. The objective of the game is as follows: given a starting point and pre-set obstacles or walls, find a way to the endpoint of the maze whilst using all available squares.

Notes: Only vertical and horizontal moves are allowed, and any square can only be used once whilst traversing the maze.

I initially thought this could be done using an A* pathfinding algorithm, but soon after realized that this is primarily used to find the smallest cost path to a given endpoint, ignoring any nodes(squares) that need not be touched. I was wondering if there was any algorithm that comes to mind or variation of pre-existing popular algorithms that would help solve this issue. This program will be written in java. Appreciate any feedback!

Note --- I have come across something known as the Hamiltonian cycle/circuit. This seems to come close to the answer I am looking for, however I want to implement this without relying on the graph providing a route back to the beginning node.

Cheers

Comment: Is [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamestart.fill&hl=en_US) the right game? Then I think you are looking for [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path)

Comment: FWIW this is known as the [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I initially thought this would not work as I was looking at Hamiltonian cycle, which is just a Hamiltonian path that has a route to the starting node. I appreciate the insight!

Comment: @MarcAcevedo You want a [Hamiltonian Path](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/hamiltonian-path/tutorial/), not Cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the help y'all! That was where my mistake was! Much appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BFS) is your friend. You could use this alog to solve you problem.